# Underdog leading at least once in an infinite series of games

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, binomial-distribution

We are observing a tournament where 2 players play a series of games. Exactly one player wins each game. So we can keep count and `5:3` might be the standing after 8 games.

The first player is the favorite and will win a game with probability $p > 1 - p$.

What is the probability that the underdog will lead the standing at least once *at some point* in an infinite series of games? Or maybe more important than the specific value: Is it $1$ or not?

Somehow I think that it should be $1$, independent of $p$, but I am not sure how much my intuition is worth here. Maybe I can take it to the infinite case with a hint about finite series of $k$ games.

Comment: Are you familiar with the strong law of large numbers ?

Comment: I can infer from it that the favorite will lead finally (and thus at some point) with probability $1$. Not sure if I can use it for saying anything about the underdog leading at least once *at some point* in the infinite series of games.

Comment: Well, if the favorite leads finally, that means that, almost surely, at some point, the count will be $5+n:3+n$ (with $n \geq 0$), and the favorite leads from there. Which means that, starting from a $5+n:3+n$ game, there is a positive probability that the favorite leads from there.

Comment: To see that it's not 1, take $p=1$ - then the second player is never ahead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order for the weaker player to go ahead on the $(2k+1)$-st game, the score must be tied after $2k$ games, and the weaker player must never have been ahead. Each string of $2k$ results in which the weaker player never leads and the final score is tied corresponds to a [Dyck word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics) of length $2k$, and there are $C_k$ such words, where $C_k$ is the $k$-th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). The probability of any such string of results is $p^k(1-p)^k$, so the probability that the weaker player first goes ahead on the $(2k+1)$-st game is $C_kp^k(1-p)^{k+1}$, and the probability that the weaker player leads at some point is

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}C_kp^k(1-p)^{k+1}=(1-p)\sum_{k\ge 0}C_k\big(p(1-p)\big)^k\;.$$

The Catalan numbers have the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof)

$$c(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0}C_kx^k=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\;,$$

so the desired probability is

$$\begin{align*}
(1-p)c\big(p(1-p)\big)&=\frac{(1-p)\left(1-\sqrt{1-4p(1-p)}\right)}{2p(1-p)}\\
&=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4p+4p^2}}{2p}\\
&=\frac{1-(2p-1)}{2p}\\
&=\frac{1-p}{p}\;.
\end{align*}$$

(This calculation does assume that $p<1$, but the result clearly holds for $p=1$ as well.)

Comment: There is a shortcut that eliminates the need to remember/look up/derive the generating function for the Catalan numbers. We have $\sum C_k p^k (1-p)^{k+1}=(1-p)/p\cdot \sum_k C_k p^{k+1} (1-p)^k = (1-p)/p\cdot $ [probability that stronger player leads at some point]. But the law of large numbers implies the stronger player leads at some point with probability $1$.

Comment: Quite an elegant solution. Definitely gonna remember Dyck words and Catalan numbers.

Comment: Although you've used $p < 1$ in your working, we don't need any fancy combinatorics to establish it's true for $p = 1$ too ;-)

Comment: This does assume $p>\frac12$.  Otherwise, when you take the square root, you get $1-2p$.  But we're assuming $p>1-p$, which is equivalent.

Comment: @Steve: *This* referred to the computation, not to the result. I took it as clear that the result held if $p=1$. However, I’ve clarified the comment.

Comment: @JulianRosen Very nice. This idea hints at a bijection between paths reaching $-k$ and those reaching $k$ and easily yields full cdf of $\min_{i\geq 0}(Win_{1i}-Win_{2i})$ not just its value value at $-1$.

Answer (score 4):

A [variant of Bertrand's ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_ballot_theorem#Variant:_ties_allowed) says that in an election where candidate A receives $a$ votes and candidate B receives $b$ votes with $a \gt b$, the probability that A will be equal to or ahead of B throughout the count is $\dfrac{a+1-b}{a+1}$, so the probability B is ever strictly ahead is $\dfrac{b}{a+1}$.

The law of large numbers implies that here $\dfrac{a}{a+b} \to p$ and thus $\dfrac{b}{a+1} \to \dfrac{1-p}{p}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y_n$ be difference of scores at time $n$ - first minus second ($Y_0=0$). Let $$m_k=P(\min_{i\geq 0}{Y_i}=-k)$$ for $k\geq0$. Then $$m_k=pm_{k+1}+(1-p)m_{k-1}$$
Solving it subject to constraint $\sum_{k\geq 0}m_k=1$ (since $Y_n\to\infty$ with probability $1$) yeilds $$m_k=(1-\alpha)\alpha^k$$ where $\alpha=\frac {1-p}p<1$. We are interested in $$P(\min_{i\geq 0}{Y_i}\leq-1)=\sum_{k\geq 1}m_k=\alpha=\frac{1-p}p$$

Comment: I don't think I understand why the second formula holds... I'm probably missing something. Would you mind adding some clarification?

Comment: From $Y_0=0$ you move up with probability $p$ and your distance from $-k$ becomes $-(k+1)$. You move down with probability $1-p$ and your distance to $-k$ becomes $-(k-1)$. Combine these two possibilities together.